# WooCommerce Custom field positioning in product details page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom field *(FECHA DE VIAJE)* in WooCommerce product details page. I have used **[WC Fields Factory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/)** plugin to add custom field. But the field is showing below the price tag but i want to show it next to the other input fields. **[This](http://paquetes.traveline.mx/producto/teotihuacan-y-basilica/)** is my website now. Could anyone tell me the hook name in WooCommerce for positioning custom field or is there any solution with CSS? Thanks in advance.

I have tried with CSS but its overlap with pricing area:

```
.wccpf-fields-group-1{ margin-top: -8%;}
```

[image]

Comment: So you should use code instead of a plugin for that (as with a plugin you get the limitations from the plugin)… There is many working examples on StackOverFlow and over internet.

Comment: Change the template

Comment: @LoicTheAztec yes i want to just little modification of that plugin. It can be with CSS or any available hook.

Comment: @MarcHjorth what do you mean by change the template? I have to work with this template. Do you have any suggestion without changing the template?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud If you want it to show next to the other inputs, you should move the custom field, next to the other inputs, in the template which is used. Then align it in the CSS with `inline-block` or whatever method you prefer :)

Comment: @MarcHjorth how can i modify this with CSS?

Comment: It might be possible with some 'hacky' `column-reverse` stuff, but I can't see the markup. Also the best way would be to change them up in the template. Since you already inserted the custom field, you should be able to change them up

Comment: To see markup inspect element can be worked. I can't do this css that's why i am asking here for help. `column-reverse` will reverse entire `column`. But i want to change just field position.